# Where can I use Ovid?

Tags: civilization-6

I got Ovid as a great person. The game tells me that Ovid "must occupy a district or wonder with a free slot of the proper Great Work type".

What are those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ovid is a Great Writer, which means he produces works of writing.

The simplest solution is to send him to your capital, as the Palace has 1 slot for any kind of great work. If your palace is full, your next best bet is to build an Amphitheatre in a Theatre District, and activate him there. (Amphitheatres have 2 slots for Great Writings).

Beyond that, some wonders also have slots for Great Works of Writing: Bolshoi Theatre, Broadway, The Great Library, and Oxford University.

Comment: Won't work in my capital, even though he is my first great person (?). Silly me - I tried campus & library. I will try an amphitheatre & get back to you

Comment: Amphitheatre worked a treat

Comment: @Mawg It's possible you have a relic (from a goodie hut or an apostle) in your capital.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. But this is my first game of 6, so I still have a lot to learn - and this seems to be the place to do it (I can remember getting a reasonably thick paper booklet with a previous version)

Comment: @Mawg: You can check the art slots (and art pieces) in one of the menus in the top left. The button that looks like a framed painting.